# Allow execution of shell script as different user from sudoers

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, sudoers

User A (no general sudo permission given) shall execute a bash script as user B.

One minimal script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
touch /home/userB/testfile
```

This script belongs to user A and shall be executed via `sudo -u userB ./script.sh` so that testfile is touched in user B's home.

In the sudoers file I added:

```
userA       ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD: /home/userA/script.sh
```

But executing `sudo -u userB /home/userA/script.sh` results in a prompt for a password of user A.

Comment: Is the sudo rule for this script the last one that's applicable for `userA`? Sudo has this odd thing where the _last_ rule matches, not the first as you'd expect.

Comment: While somewhat different using a sticky bit might be a possible solution.

Comment: @Seth You probably mean the `setuid` bit, not the sticky bit. `setuid` is 4 in octal presentation, the sticky bit is 1, and ignored on Linux (historically used to keep executables in memory, hence the _sticky_). In fact, in most modern Unices, `setuid` is disabled for shell scripts (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/).

Comment: @Seth like mtak assumed, setuid does not work for shell scripts on my fedora installation. And if possible I'd like to avoid to compile a wrapper application.

Comment: @mtak I added it within a new file in sudoers.d, which is included by sudoers in its last line. And in sudoers.d is no other file, which could interfere. Interestingly if I add any other command instead of the script, I can execute the command as userB without password. Any problem maybe regarding the bash shell? Do I need to add bash for example? But adding bash itself sounds unsecure